# Output a backslash in groff, also avoiding hyphenation

Tags: printing, formatting, groff

How groff can output `\` symbol in my text, do not reading this symbol as a macro?
And how to prohibit dividing words with a dash (hyphenation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a printing version of the backslash with `\e` according to the manpage.

And there is `.nh` for »no hyphenation«.

Comment: Actually the man page says: "(...)`\e` represents the current  escape  character.   To  get  a backslash glyph, use `\(rs` or `\[rs]`."

Answer (score 0):

For me, writing `\\` as a sort of *escape sequence* works fine and outputs a singe backslash "\".